# OpenTelemetry: Difference between traceidratio & parentbased_traceidratio

Tags: python, jaeger, opentracing, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

According to the [document](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/7fc28733eb3791ebcc98fed0d858a7961f1e95b2/specification/sdk-environment-variables.md#general-sdk-configuration)

- "traceidratio": TraceIdRatioBased
- "parentbased_traceidratio": ParentBased(root=TraceIdRatioBased)

What I understood:

- `traceidratio` will do sampling irrespective of whether sampling is done at source/parent. (Meaning: a sampled trace be sampled again??)
- `parentbased_traceidratio` would respect the sampling flag on the basis of the parent.

But doesn't seem so I think. What is the difference between the two?

**Background:**
Setting sampling on `istio` to `100` and setting the environment variable to `OTEL_TRACES_SAMPLER` to `traceidratio` or `parentbased_traceidratio`and `OTEL_TRACES_SAMPLER_ARG` to `0.001` did not show any reduction/sampling from the application itself. (All traces we available on jaeger indicating there was no reduction or sampling). A simple python based app that uses [open-telemetry-python](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python). setting OTEL to debug logs did not show anything specific either.

By documentation setting the env variables should change the sampling of traces in the application.

Answer (score 0):

`traceidratio` will ignore the decision made on the parent span and will make a new one based on the ratio.
A span can't be sampled twice. When creating a span, we make a sampling decision, which happens once; either we make a new decision or respect the parent's decision.

So setting `OTEL_TRACES_SAMPLER` to `traceidratio` with `0.001` should reduce the number of spans.